# Efficient way to represent a voxel by a vector consisting of neighbouring cells in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d

For a 3D image, I would like to represent each voxel as a 3D patch consisting of neighbouring voxels (of radius r and includes padding if needed). So the result would be a 4D vector. I'm quite new to this. I haven't been able to find an existing library that implements this. My approach would be to Pad the image with r voxels on each side and take 'n' 3D patches with the target voxel being at the center. Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65398503/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would help to see code for your attempt at this. By "representing each voxel as a 3D patch", do you mean just extracting a sub-array of the sample values in the neighborhood, or "patch" in the sense of 3D polygons? In what sense is the desired result a 4D vector?

Comment: Hello @PascalGetreuer, I am still in the process of writing the code. I'll put it up once I get the desired solution. the neighbourhood refers to 3d polygon of radius r. by 4D vector I mean, For each voxel (dimension 1) - there will be a 3D polygon (3D).